# Request method 'POST' not supported | SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring, post, spring-mvc, spring-boot, get

estoy intentado montar un simple menu de inicio y me da error en el metodo POST al pulsar el boton del submit.

Mi controlador con el metodo post llamado por el submit en html con valor "login"
[image: Mi controlador con el metodo post llamado por el submit en html con valor "login"]

Mi index.html
[image: Mi index.html]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Es importante que, en lugar de poner imagenes, copies y pegues tu código, para que si alguien quiere probarlo no tenga que teclearlo de nuevo.

Comment: En vez de usar la anotacion RequestMapping en tu metodo de login prueba usar PostMapping con el value "/login".

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder tan rápido, he usado lo que me ha comentado y sigue dando el mismo error:There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Se lo pones difícil a los demás poniendo código como imagen. Estás pidiéndole a otros que desinteresadamente transcriban tu código para intentar replicar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tu clase debe ir asi:

```
@RequestMapping(/usuario/**)
```

Después tu login tiene que ir:

```
@RequestMapping(value="login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Que es así como tienes el login.

Como tu lo tienes, solo te esta esperando una url tipo_

```
tuServidor/usuario
```

Lo demás lo descarta.

Con las modificaciones que te digo puedes acceder como:

```
tuServidor:[8080]/usuario/login
```

La manera en que entres depende de como tienes configurado tu servidor.

Si quieres implementar seguridad te recomiendo utilices la capa de spring security. Te va a facilitar la vida despues de que le entiendas.